# YUI (JS): Putting a MenuBar in a Panel

Tags: javascript, yui, panel, menubar

If I put a YUI menu bar in the body it works perfectly. However if I use it inside of a Panel it shows up without the proper background. It is larger than it should be. Other than the default sam skin I'm using only the following css. .windowbody is the class of the panel.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.windowbody {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.windowbody div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on the same problem and I was delighted to finally find one more person who is trying to do the same as I am.  I can't find any examples on the otherwise excellent YUI documentation pages so I've uploaded a solution to the problem at this address:http://catalinabuilder.hostjava.net/exercisepanel.html